# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of the following series. But I'm not having success in finding it.

Convergence of the series : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+nx)^n}{n!}$$

Thank you.

Comment: You aren’t having success? Can you detail one of your failed attempts?

Answer (score 1):

By the root test, you require 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|1+nx|}{(n!)^{1/n}}<1
$$
but by Stirling's,
$$
n!\sim n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\implies (n!)^{1/n}\sim n^{1+1/2n}e^{-1}\sim n/e
$$
and so your requirement is 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|1+nx|}{n}e<1\implies |x|<1/e
$$

Comment: How $n^{1 + \frac{1}{2n}} \approx n$ like how $n^{\frac{1}{2n} } \approx 1$ ?

Comment: you may check the second by using the exponential logarithm trick and the first will follow

Comment: It's helpful. Have you any other approach without using Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @B.R.Datt you can probably use the ratio test, but at first glance it looked unpleasant

Comment: Yes. I've checked the series by ratio test. But I'm upset with it. It's incomplete to me by ratio test.